# PHP mysqli returns wrong columns

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm writing a simple PHP cgi program that needs to use MySql.  I started with two columns in the players table, and my SELECT worked fine.  I have added another column since then called class_id.  When I do a SELECT now, I get three entries back in $row, but the third entry is called players instead of class_id.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM players";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ){
  do something
}
```

The schema:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `asrleague`.`players`;
CREATE TABLE  `asrleague`.`players` (
  `player_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `kgs_handle` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `class_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`player_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Is PHP caching info about the table somewhere, and I need to get it to refresh somehow?

I'm also seeing this warning, which has been there all the time:

```
<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli::mysqli() [<a href='mysqli.mysqli'>mysqli.mysqli</a>]: Headers and client library minor version mismatch. Headers:50145 Library:50018 in ...
```

I'm not sure if that's related or not, but it was there before the problem started.

Answer (score 2):

Some Googling on your error message, gives those interesting threads:

- http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/php-34/just-starting-loading-php-ini-664446.html
- http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?52,290016,290016#msg-290016

Seems that a reinstallation of PHP could be necessary.

Quoting an answer (anishmsry's) from the first link (bold is from me):

> Hi bmcgill... i had installed php,
>   mysql and apache some months ago in my
>   computer following the instructions
>   from kevin's book. and there was no
>   problem. everything was working fine.
>
> i bought a new computer last week and
>   installed the latest versions in the
>   new computer. after installing and
>   running it. i got the error which u
>   got: Warning: mysqli_connect()
>   [function.mysqli-connect]: Headers and
>   client library minor version mismatch.
>   Headers:50051 Library:50145
>
> i reinstalled everything and again i
>   was receiving the same error. i had
>   the same conf for mysql, php and
>   apache as u've mentioned.
>
> **i uninstalled apache and php. and
>   installed the earlier versions which i
>   was using: apache- 2.2.11 and
>   php-5.3.0. this time everything was
>   working fine and there was no error**
>
> well it just worked like that for me.
>   that's why i'm telling. i don't know
>   why it worked now.
>
> i was searching about this issue in
>   net, and in a forum in mysql's website
>   i found that some other person had
>   this problem with a much earlier
>   versions. he reinstalled php and the
>   problem was solved.